# script not working on document.ready in Safari & Chrome (FF okay), but works on document.resize

Tags: jquery, cross-browser

I have the following jquery script to resize an image and give it a left margin to horizontally center it. The script works perfectly in FF, but in Safari and Chrome I have problems.

Safari & Chrome prob: the image resizes okay, but the leftMargin appears to be set *before* the image is resized resulting in an image that is pushed much too far left. This problem occurs only on document.ready. When resizing the browser, the script works fine.

```
function imageresize() {
    var h = $(window).height(),
        w = $(window).width(),
        newHeight = h * 0.5,
        newTopMargin = newHeight * 0.12;

        $('img.resize').css({'height' : newHeight + 'px', 'margin-top' : '-' + newTopMargin + 'px'});
    var leftMargin = (w - ($('img.resize').width()))/2;
        $('img.resize').css('margin-left', leftMargin + 'px');

}
$(document).ready(function() {
  imageresize();
});

$(window).resize(function() {
  imageresize();
});
```

The script is placed before `</body>`.

Any assistance would be much appreciated!

Comment: you could always try putting it in a SetTimeout(1) and see if that helps :)

Comment: Whenever possible, avoid trying to time things like that. JS is event driven so it should be loaded on the proper trigger and not assume it takes 1 second to load.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The document ready event can fire before images have finished loading. Try binding to window, or images' [load event](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) instead.

```
$(window).load(function() {
  imageresize();
});

// or

$('img').load(function() {
  imageresize();
});
```

Comment: Perfect - window.load works in all the browsers! I'm still learning a lot about jquery - I thought document.ready was always best to use! Many thanks :-)

Comment: The point of jQuery is to work across all browsers! At any rate, document ready is _usually_ the best choice ...until, of course, your code depends on images being loaded.

Answer (score 1):

If its just one image, you could also bind to the image load event.

```
$(img).load(function() {
  imageresize();
});
```