# Simple javascript in Safari won't work

Tags: jquery, safari

I have the following javascript that works on Firefox, IE, iPhones and iPads, but I can't get it to work on Safari... its very simple!

```
jQuery(window).ready(function(){
  alert('hi');
});
```

What am I doing wrong? There are no errors in the console. Originally I had it as `jQuery(document).read` but that made no difference.

Comment: And ... what errors are in the console?

Comment: Try `$(document).ready()`

Comment: See my question- there are no errors in the console.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).ready(function(){
  alert('hi');
});
```

should work "i think", but try:

```
$(window).load(function() {
      alert("window load occurred!");
});
```

Comment: There shouldn't be any reason that `jQuery` shouldn't work, as `$` is just the alias for `jQuery`.

Comment: you should try to check your console error, will be easier to debug.

Comment: @LiccyFuentes: if nobody is debating the use of the $, then what is the difference between your answer and what I posted in my question? Also- I said in my original question that the console is empty and not showing any errors.

Answer (score 0):

I used `$(document).ready();` and didn't get problem so far with my works

Comment: Yep I'm sure it works for others, but it doesn't for me. There must be something in the page that is conflicting.

Comment: Try viewing the source page and check everything. I believe there can be conflicts. But it should be working :| weird

Answer (score 0):

So if I use the following ([Found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5698641/script-not-working-on-document-ready-in-safari-chrome-ff-okay-but-works-on)):

```
jQuery(window).load(function(){})
```

It works! Does Safari not like document.load??