# JS Chrome document ready in template works in some cases but not in others

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, grails

I'm on grails project.

In `Firefox` it's fine but `Chrome`.

2 pages, both request to controller and render a template. 
In the first one, I alert 1 in

```
$(document).ready(function(){alert(1)})
```

, it works. But in other request, it alerts nothing.

Please helps me to get through.  Thanks.

Bellow is my source code:

This called from first page and it works.

```
function addDoc() {
        $.get("<g:createLink action="getTemplate" controller="attachDocument"/>", {
            proNum: $("#proNum").val(),
            type: 'FS',
            cusCode: $("#codeCustomer").val()




}, function (data) {
            $("#addDocBox").html(data)
            $("#addDocBox").dialog("open");
        });
    }
```

This called from other page and it not works.

```
function addDoc() {
        $.get("<g:createLink action="getTemplate" controller="attachDocument"/>", {
            proNum: $("#invoiceNo").val(),
            type: '${marine.ConstantMessage.MI}',
            cusCode: $("#codeCustomer").val()
        }, function (data) {
            $("#addDocBox").html(data);
            $("#addDocBox").dialog("open");
        });
    }
```

Note: data is template html as bellow:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
  alert(1)
});
```

Comment: Have you opened the developer console in chrome to see if any errors are being generated when it does not work ?

Comment: Console show nothing

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5698641/script-not-working-on-document-ready-in-safari-chrome-ff-okay-but-works-on