# JavaScript not loading on production site with Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, safari, haml

JavaScript works fine both locally *and* production on Chrome, but when I try in Safari, it doesn't.  I would think the solution would be to enable JavaScript on Safari, but I do have it enabled, and it's working locally on Safari. It just doesn't work on production.  I would think there's a problem with how I'm pushing up to production, but my production environment is working on Chrome.

I'm using Rails with jQuery Turbolinks.

My application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require social-share-button
//= require zeroclipboard
//= require google_analytics
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

A sample JS file that isn't loading correctly:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var referLinkClip = new ZeroClipboard($("#referral-text-button"))
  var referCodeClip = new ZeroClipboard($("#referral-code-button"))
  var embedClip = new ZeroClipboard($("#embed-text-button"))
  alert('foobar');
  $(".copy-button").hover(function(){
    $(this).css('background-color', '#7b7b7b');
    }, function(){
    $(this).css("background-color", '#949494');
  });
  $(".copy-button").click(function(){
    $(this).css('outline', 'none');
    $(this).css('background-color', '#2d3538');
    setTimeout(function(){
      $(this).css('background-color', '#949494');
    }, 100);
  });
});
```

My view using this JS (HAML):

```
%button#referral-code-button.plan-show.round-corners-8px.col-md-2.referral-links.copy-button{:'data-clipboard-target'=>'referral-code'}
  Copy code
.plan-show.round-corners-8px.col-md-8.referral-links.light-text
  Your affiliate code:
  %span#referral-code.medium-text= "#{current_user.affiliate_code}"
```

This all works fine in Chrome locally and on production, but just not on production in Safari. I've compiled my assets with `bundle exec rake assets:precompile`, and it makes no difference.

Any ideas? I'm stumped.

**Edit:**

More info that may prove useful... Recently, even on Chrome, I've had trouble getting the JS to load properly unless the page is refreshed. In the JS file I provided, the `$(".copy-button").click` function works (button changes color), but neither the `$(".copy-button").hover` works, nor do the `ZeroClipboard` objects initialize. I'm including the JS in my `application.html` head, with `=javascript_include_tag 'application'`

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5698641/script-not-working-on-document-ready-in-safari-chrome-ff-okay-but-works-on

Comment: @Vivasaayi unfortunately, I've tried the solutions mentioned there, including using `$(window).load`, `$(document).on("pagechange")`, `$(document).on("pageinit")`, and `$(document).on("init")`. I'm open to any others, though, because it seems to be a problem with _when_ it loads.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue (see [Safari iOS not loading Javascript file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38534765/safari-ios-not-loading-javascript-file/38920288#38920288)) and found that the reason was Safari automatically sandboxing (blocking all JS execution) on requests done using HTTP/0.9.

For more details check out my answer in the other thread.