# How to change HTTP version in rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, safari

I encountered this issue : [Safari iOS not loading Javascript file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38534765/safari-ios-not-loading-javascript-file/38920288#38920288) => and I tried to follow the first answer.

"Make sure your web server supports HTTP/1.1 and that you request the page using HTTP/1.1"

How can I check that and change the version in my app if needed ?
I'm using rails 5.

Comment: You have to look at the request headers. You will see a line like `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` where the value after `HTTP/` is the version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this**

```
if request.env["HTTP_VERSION"] == "HTTP/1.1"
   return head :bad_request
end
```