# Forcing Flask to return HTTP version in response

Tags: python, http, flask, http-headers

I'm having problem on a particular device (iPhone SE, iOS 9.3.5). Reading this other [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38534765/safari-ios-not-loading-javascript-file), it seems that safari thinks that the web server is using HTTP/0.9, and the issue can be solved by including the HTTP version in the response. I'm using templates, if that matters.

I've tried this:

```
@downloader.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('home.html', name=get_guest_name()), "HTTP/1.1 200 OK", {"Content-Type": "text/html"}
```

But this does not seem to work. Desktop browsers and other mobile devices work just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to wrap your `render_template()` result (which is a `str`) in a [`Response` using `make_response()`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.Flask.make_response), attach the desired headers, e.g. along these lines:

```
@downloader.route('/')
def home():
    resp = make_response(render_template('home.html', name=get_guest_name()))
    resp.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/html'
    return resp
```

You could make this into decorator to have it easily reusable.