# $.getScript error in iOS Safari - works in Chrome

Tags: jquery, ios, safari, mobile-application, getscript

I am loading a static resource file through `$.getScript` as below. `loadTestComponents` is a function defined within the example.js file. This works as expected in Chrome but it's not working in iOS Safari.

I'm getting an error:

> loadTestComponents is undefined

```js
$.getScript(getParameterByName('srURL') + '/example.js', function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
  console.log(textStatus); // Success
  console.log(jqxhr.status); // 200
  console.log("Load was performed.");
  console.log(data);
  loadTestComponents();
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Safari iOS not loading Javascript file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38534765/safari-ios-not-loading-javascript-file)

Comment: in my case it is loading the script. console.log(data) shows the function. but when invoke it, its not recognised